# dynamic routing with nextjs before the page name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

I am using react with Nextjs and i would like to use a dynamic name before the page name instead after.

Per example i have 2 files about.tsx and music.tsx wish loads as:

localhost:3000/about

localhost:3000/music

What i would like is:

localhost:3000/nirvana/about

localhost:3000/nirvana/music

localhost:3000/metalica/about

localhost:3000/metalica/music

and to be able to identify the dynamic slug before the page name, so i can know which band name is, does anyone know how to do this with nextjs?

thank you

Comment: does this help? https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/dynamic-api-routes

Comment: that article only explains to use a slug at the end in my case i want to be able to add before the page name, so the page name is fixed and the slug before is a dynamic name

Answer (score 1):

You can create `pages/[music_type]/about.js` and `pages/[music_type]/music.js` files to make `music_type` dynamic. You can even add dynamic route for '/about ' and '/music' by creating `pages/[music_type]/[sub].js`

Comment: Let me know if this answer was helpful

Comment: i only find information about using the slug after but not before a page name, let me know if you know how to be able to do this, thank you

Comment: This answer has explained how to create a dynamic route. If you have tried the solution above please update your question to show your attempt so we can help debug.